# "exceptions.TypeError: list indices must be integers not str" in python with Elasticsearch

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, urllib2

I try to obtain the id of document with my function, but I've got this error:

```
    var = data['hits']['hits']['_id']
exceptions.TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

my little function:

```
def FoundIdDocument(reference):
    print "foundiddocument"
    url = BuildUrl()+'_search?q=name:"'+reference.replace(' ','%20')+'"'
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    out = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    data = out.read()
    print data
    # returned data is JSON            
    data = json.loads(data)
    # total number of results    
    var = data['hits']['hits']['_id']
    print var
```

Comment: One of the things you think is a dictionary is actually a list. It could be `data['hits']`. It could be `data['hits']['hits']`. It could be `data['hits']['hits']['_id']`.

Comment: I've found this solution:
for index in  data['hits']['hits']:
        return index['_id']

Comment: I don't understand your solution above. The loop will execute at most once. So the difference will occur when `data['hits']['hits']` is empty and the loop does not execute or `data['hits']['hits']` has a dictionary that has a key `_id`. But in no case does this help where one of your data structures is a list instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print the keys and figure it out:

```
print data.keys()
# Does it have 'hits'? If yes, do this:
print data['hits'].keys()
# Does it have 'hits'? If yes, do this:
print data['hits']['hits'].keys()
# You should have hit an error by this point
```

Comment: This won't show what *value* is a list; all you'll get is an attribute error, as lists don't have a `.keys()` method.

Comment: Fair enough. The method is sound but the comments are in error.

Comment: See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_the_search_api.html, `data['hits']['hits']` is a list.

Comment: The @pi-2r's solution does not work: ` for index in data['hits']['hits']: return index['_id']`

Comment: It does, actually, but they could just as well have used `data['hits']['hits'][0]['_id']`, provided they handle the `IndexError` when the list is empty.